# c# Double.TryParse("1,1,1", out value) returns true, value = 111 huh?

Tags: c#, .net

in the immed window:

```
?Double.Parse("4,67,34,34,46,34,235,346")
46734344634235344.0
```

How to I stop this and only allow 4.56  4,455,455.33, 1.23E5 to succeed?

Comment: Perhaps you could clarify what you are trying to achieve. There is no way to "stop" the Parse method from working as it does.

Comment: Writing numbers like `"4,67,34,34,46,34,235,346"` is common in India. If you scroll to the bottom of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_separator you'll see a couple different methods similar to this.

Comment: really, this question seems to have no sense

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an overload `Double.Parse(String, NumberStyles)` that allow you to specify what is allowed. See [this msdn page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7yd1h1be.aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

[TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/994c0zb1.aspx) accepts culture-specific group separators anywhere in the input string. The accepted format is

```
[ws][sign][integral-digits,]integral-digits[.[fractional-digits]][e[sign]exponential-digits][ws]
```

Where , is the culture-specific group separator and . is the decimal point.

With my current locale setting the following

```
double d;
Console.WriteLine(double.TryParse("1.1.1,2", out d)); // one decimal point, two group separators
Console.WriteLine(d);
```

evaluates to true and 111,2 while

```
double d;
Console.WriteLine(double.TryParse("1.1.1,2,2", out d)); // two decimal points
Console.WriteLine(d);
```

evaluates to false and 0.